# Get ajax jquery to reset when i click on another link

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

index.php

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('a.bruker').click(function() {

            var idx = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
                url:'bruker.php',
                type:'POST',
                data: 'id='+idx,
                cache: false,
                success:function(data) { 
                    $('#bruker').html(data);
                }
        });
    });
    });
    echo "<div id='bruker'></div>";
    <a class='bruker' id='1'>name1</a>
    <a class='bruker' id='2'>name2</a>
```

bruker.php

```
if(isset($_POST['id'])) {
    echo "<script> $(function() {
    $('.bruker-box').dialog({
        autoOpen:true,
        resizable: false,
        closeOnEscape: true,
        width:600,
        height:500,
        show: 'fade',
        modal: true,
        open: function(event, ui) {  },
        position: { my: 'center', at: 'center' }
    })
    $('#ui-id-2').css('border', 'none');
    $('.ui-widget-overlay').click (function () {
    $('.bruker-box').dialog( 'close' );
});

  });</script>";

echo "<div class='bruker-box' title='(".$_POST['id'].")'>";
echo "example";
echo "</div>";
```

When i click out of the first box (name1) and click on name2 i want to get only the name 2 to come up, but the first box (name1) comming up first and than name2.

How can i get this right? Is there a way to reset somthing when i click on a new one?

Comment: So you then have two divs with the class bruker-box?

Comment: If i click on name1, and quit that box, than click on name2 the name1 shows first and i quit name1, name2 show up. Understand?

Comment: I understand but I was wondering if you have the box twice in your DOM. Btw I find it disturbing that you have mixed Javascript, PHP and HTML without any separators in your code.

Comment: How can i check if i have the box twice in DOM?

Sry, im new to javascript and so.

Comment: Something like rightclick->Inspect Element ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because, every time an anchor is clicked, you are injecting a new div containing a dialog set to autoOpen.  (*Turn on Developer Tools F12 in Chrome and watch what happens.*)

The autoOpen divs accumulate, redisplaying themselves with each change to the DOM.

To solve this, you can `remove()` the div after it displays. Change your `bruker.php` file to look like this:

*Note the addition of a `close:` function in the dialog definition:*

**PHP:**

```
if(isset($_POST['id'])) {
    $out = "
    <script> 
        $(function() {
            $('.bruker-box').dialog({
                autoOpen:true,
                resizable: false,
                closeOnEscape: true,
                width:600,
                height:500,
                show: 'fade',
                modal: true,
                open: function(event, ui) {  },
                position: { my: 'center', at: 'center' },
                close: function() {
                    $('div.ui-dialog').remove();
                }
            }); //END .dialog()

            $('#ui-id-2').css('border', 'none');

            $('.ui-widget-overlay').click (function () {
                $('.bruker-box').dialog( 'close' );
            });

        }); //END document.ready
    </script>";

    $out .= "<div class='bruker-box' title='Name: (" .$_POST['id']. ")'>";
    $out .= "example";
    $out .= "</div>";
    echo $out;
}
```

Comment: thank you. I understand a little bit more what I have done wrong.